# create updateable program in C# (online update)

Tags: c#

i need create who can update before start program.

I'm very search and find : **ClickOnce**  and use it

but this is not work for me , why ? i don't know !

any way how can create it ?
i need for this .
and i need check for update before start program .
and update from my host

how can i do ?
what do i do ?

only with **ClickOnce** ? 
if Yes, can u help me for use ClickOnce

or can u help me for other way ?
please give me a easy way for this !

**i need Explanation of ClickOnce ,
 how can set it for update from myhost ?**

Comment: How about copy very update on floppy with install on user computer manually!

Comment: @ Polity : ummmm , good idea :)))ha ha .  but I'm in Germany and and  user live in turkey !

Comment: @ SWeko : i'm open program but not check for update

Answer (score 0):

I did it,At first time when App starts I check the version if it changed 
I start Updater App with System.Diagnostics.Process.Start and then Close current App,the updater will update the app and then start it by System.Diagnostics.Process.Start

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce is the most easy way to do auto-update for .NET Windows application, I don't know what's your problem with it. Anyway [NetSparkle](http://netsparkle.codeplex.com/) is an alternative choice, it's a good auto-update package for .NET application.

Comment: I'm use .net 2 & 3 & 3.5 but this is need for 4 >>check later